# Can this Oracle SQL query be simplified?

Tags: sql, oracle, function

Is there a way I can write this better? The way it's currently written is taking a long time to pull the data. The results of the data also repeat data multiple lines with the same info. Any suggestions? I tried changing the join clauses but that didn't help much. I'm not sure what else I could use to shorten the query to make it run smoother and get better results.

```
select 
PT_IDENTIFIER.PT_IDENTIFIER_VALUE, 
PT_STUDY.FK_SOCRD_ID, 
patient.PTLASTNAME || ', ' || patient.PTFIRSTNAME as "Patient name", 
patient.DOB, 
PT_STUDY.SUBJECT_NUMBER, 
CR_imaging.CR_IMAGING as "CR_Imaging", 
CR_imaging.CR_IMAGING_SPEC, 
CR_IMAGING.CR_IMAGING_DT, 
CR_imaging.CR_IMG_SITE, 
CR_IMAGING.CR_IMG_SITE_SPEC, 
CR_IMAGING.CR_IMAGING_CT, 
CR_IMAGING.CR_IMAGING_CN, 
CR_IMAGING.CR_IMAGING_CM, 
CR_WORKUPPROC.CR_WORKUPPROC,
CR_WORKUPPROC.CR_WORKUPPROC_DT, 
CR_DISEASE_HISTORY.CR_DISEASE_HISTORY,
CR_DISEASE_HISTORY.CR_DISEASE_HISTORY_DT, 
CR_MDT.CR_MDT_DT, 
CR_MDT.CR_MDT_DIAG, 
CR_MDT.CR_MDT_PHYS, 
CR_MDT.CR_MDT_PRESENTED, 
CR_MDT.CR_MDT_HISTTYPE, 
CR_MDT.CR_MDT_STAGE, 
CR_MDT.CR_MDT_CT, 
CR_MDT.CR_MDT_CN, 
CR_MDT.CR_MDT_CM, 
CR_MDT.CR_MDT_PT, 
CR_MDT.CR_MDT_PN, 
CR_MDT.CR_MDT_PM, 
CR_MDT.CR_MDT_LOOKBACK, 
CR_MDT_PATH_REVIEW_DT, 
CR_MDT_PATH_REVIEW, 
CR_MDT_RECOM.CR_MDT_RECOM, 
CR_MDT_RECOM.CR_MDT_RECOM_SPEC, 
TUMORSITE.DIAGNOSIS_DT, 
TUMORSITE.TUMORSITE, 
TUMORSITE.TUMORSITE_SPEC, 
TUMORSITE.RECURRENCE_DT, 
TUMORSITE.RECURRENCE_DT_EST, 
TUMORSITE.METASTASIS_DT, 
TUMORSITE.METASTASIS_DT_EST, 
CR_SYSTEMIC.CR_AGENT, 
CR_SYSTEMIC.CR_AGENT_SPEC, 
CR_SYSTEMIC.CR_SYS_CYCLE, 
CR_SYSTEMIC.CR_SYS_DOSE_DAY, 
CR_SYSTEMIC.CR_SYS_DOSE_TOTAL, 
CR_SYSTEMIC.CR_SYS_START_DT, 
CR_SYSTEMIC.CR_SYS_START_DT_EST, 
CR_SYSTEMIC.CR_SYS_END_DT, 
CR_SYSTEMIC.CR_SYS_END_DT_EST, 
CR_RADIATION.CR_RAD_START_DT, 
CR_RADIATION.CR_RAD_START_DT_EST, 
CR_RADIATION.CR_RAD_END_DT, 
CR_RADIATION.CR_RAD_END_DT_EST,
CR_RADIATION.CR_RAD_PHYS,
CR_RADIATION.CR_RAD_DOSE, 
CR_RADIATION.CR_RAD_NOTES, 
CR_SURGERY.CR_SURGERY_DT, 
CR_SURGERY.CR_SURGERY, 
CR_SURGERY.CR_SURGEON, 
CR_SURGERY.CR_SURGERY_DT_EST, 
CR_SURGERY.CR_SURG_APPROACH, 
CR_SURGERY.CR_SURGERY_SPEC, 
CR_PATHOLOGY.CR_SURG_PT, 
CR_PATHOLOGY.CR_SURG_PN, 
CR_PATHOLOGY.CR_SURG_PM, 
CR_PATHOLOGY.CR_SURG_HISTTYPE, 
CR_PATHOLOGY.CR_SURG_TME, 
CR_PATHOLOGY.CR_SURG_TME_REASON, 
CR_PATHOLOGY.CR_SURG_TME_REASON_SPEC, 
CR_PATHOLOGY.CR_SURG_DISTAL, 
CR_PATHOLOGY.CR_SURG_MSI, 
CR_PATHOLOGY.CR_SURG_CRM, 
CR_PATHOLOGY.CR_SURG_PROX_DIST, 
FU_STATUS.FU_DT,
FU_STATUS.FU_STATUS, 
FU_STATUS.FU_CANCERSTATUS, 
CR_LAB.CR_LAB_DT, 
CR_LAB_TUMORMARKER.CR_LAB_TUMORMARKER, 
CR_DISEASE_HISTORY.CR_FAM_HISTORY, 
CR_GENTEST.CR_GENTEST, 
CR_GENTEST.CR_GENTEST_SPEC, 
CR_GENTEST.CR_GENTEST_DT,
CR_GENTEST.CR_GENTEST_RESULT
from 
CR_IMAGING 
left join patient 
on CR_IMAGING.fk_SOCRD_ID=patient.SOCRD_ID 
left join PT_IDENTIFIER 
on patient.socrd_id=PT_IDENTIFIER.FK_SOCRD_ID 
left join PT_STUDY 
on patient.SOCRD_ID=PT_STUDY.FK_SOCRD_ID 
left join CR_DISEASE_HISTORY 
on CR_DISEASE_HISTORY.FK_SOCRD_ID=patient.SOCRD_ID 
left join CR_MDT 
on CR_MDT.FK_SOCRD_ID=PATIENT.SOCRD_ID 
left join CR_MDT_RECOM 
on CR_MDT.CR_MDT_ID=CR_MDT_RECOM.FK_CR_MDT_ID 
left join tumorsite 
on tumorsite.FK_SOCRD_ID=PATIENT.SOCRD_ID 
left join CR_SYSTEMIC 
on CR_SYSTEMIC.FK_SOCRD_ID=PATIENT.SOCRD_ID 
left join CR_RADIATION 
on CR_RADIATION.FK_SOCRD_ID=PATIENT.SOCRD_ID 
left join CR_SURGERY 
on CR_SURGERY.FK_SOCRD_ID=PATIENT.SOCRD_ID 
LEFT JOIN FU_STATUS 
ON FU_STATUS.FK_SOCRD_ID=PATIENT.SOCRD_ID 
LEFT JOIN CR_LAB 
ON CR_LAB.FK_SOCRD_ID=PATIENT.SOCRD_ID 
LEFT JOIN CR_LAB_TUMORMARKER 
ON CR_LAB_TUMORMARKER.FK_CR_LAB_ID=CR_LAB.CR_LAB_ID 
left join CR_PATHOLOGY 
on CR_PATHOLOGY.FK_CR_SURGERY_ID=CR_SURGERY.CR_SURGERY_ID, 
cr_workupproc CR_WORKUPPROC 
where cr_workupproc.FK_SOCRD_ID=patient.SOCRD_ID 
and CR_DISEASE_HISTORY.FK_SOCRD_ID=patient.SOCRD_ID 
and PT_STUDY=3 
GROUP BY PT_STUDY.SUBJECT_NUMBER, 
patient.PTLASTNAME, patient.PTFIRSTNAME, 
CR_imaging.CR_IMAGING, 
CR_IMAGING.CR_IMAGING_DT, patient.DOB, 
CR_imaging.CR_IMG_SITE, 
CR_IMAGING.CR_IMG_SITE_SPEC, 
CR_imaging.CR_IMAGING_SPEC, 
CR_IMAGING.CR_IMAGING_CT, 
CR_IMAGING.CR_IMAGING_CN, 
CR_IMAGING.CR_IMAGING_CM, 
CR_WORKUPPROC.CR_WORKUPPROC, 
CR_WORKUPPROC.CR_WORKUPPROC_DT, 
CR_DISEASE_HISTORY.CR_DISEASE_HISTORY, 
CR_DISEASE_HISTORY.CR_DISEASE_HISTORY_DT, 
CR_MDT_RECOM.CR_MDT_RECOM, 
CR_MDT.CR_MDT_DT, 
CR_MDT.CR_MDT_PHYS, 
CR_MDT.CR_MDT_PRESENTED, 
CR_MDT.CR_MDT_HISTTYPE, 
CR_MDT.CR_MDT_STAGE, 
CR_MDT.CR_MDT_CT, 
CR_MDT.CR_MDT_CN, 
CR_MDT.CR_MDT_CM, 
CR_MDT.CR_MDT_LOOKBACK, 
CR_MDT.CR_MDT_PT, 
CR_MDT.CR_MDT_PN, 
CR_MDT.CR_MDT_PM, 
CR_MDT_PATH_REVIEW_DT, 
CR_MDT_PATH_REVIEW, 
TUMORSITE.TUMORSITE, 
TUMORSITE.TUMORSITE_SPEC, 
TUMORSITE.RECURRENCE_DT, 
TUMORSITE.RECURRENCE_DT_EST, 
TUMORSITE.METASTASIS_DT, 
TUMORSITE.METASTASIS_DT_EST, 
CR_SYSTEMIC.CR_AGENT, 
CR_SYSTEMIC.CR_AGENT_SPEC, 
CR_SYSTEMIC.CR_SYS_CYCLE, 
CR_SYSTEMIC.CR_SYS_DOSE_DAY, 
CR_SYSTEMIC.CR_SYS_DOSE_TOTAL, 
CR_SYSTEMIC.CR_SYS_START_DT, 
CR_SYSTEMIC.CR_SYS_START_DT_EST, 
CR_SYSTEMIC.CR_SYS_END_DT, 
CR_SYSTEMIC.CR_SYS_END_DT_EST, 
CR_RADIATION.CR_RAD_START_DT, 
CR_RADIATION.CR_RAD_START_DT_EST, 
CR_RADIATION.CR_RAD_END_DT, 
CR_RADIATION.CR_RAD_END_DT_EST, 
CR_RADIATION.CR_RAD_PHYS, 
CR_RADIATION.CR_RAD_DOSE,
CR_RADIATION.CR_RAD_NOTES, 
CR_SURGERY.CR_SURGERY_DT, 
CR_SURGERY.CR_SURGERY,
CR_SURGERY.CR_SURGEON,
CR_SURGERY.CR_SURGERY_DT_EST,
CR_SURGERY.CR_SURG_APPROACH, 
CR_PATHOLOGY.CR_SURG_PT, 
CR_PATHOLOGY.CR_SURG_PN, 
CR_PATHOLOGY.CR_SURG_PM,
CR_PATHOLOGY.CR_SURG_HISTTYPE, 
CR_PATHOLOGY.CR_SURG_TME, 
CR_PATHOLOGY.CR_SURG_TME_REASON, 
CR_PATHOLOGY.CR_SURG_TME_REASON_SPEC, 
CR_PATHOLOGY.CR_SURG_DISTAL, 
CR_PATHOLOGY.CR_SURG_MSI, 
CR_PATHOLOGY.CR_SURG_CRM, 
CR_PATHOLOGY.CR_SURG_PROX_DIST, 
PT_STUDY.FK_SOCRD_ID, 
CR_MDT.CR_MDT_DIAG, 
FU_STATUS.FU_DT,
FU_STATUS.FU_STATUS,
FU_STATUS.FU_CANCERSTATUS, 
PT_IDENTIFIER_VALUE, 
CR_MDT_RECOM.CR_MDT_RECOM_SPEC, 
TUMORSITE.DIAGNOSIS_DT, 
CR_LAB.CR_LAB_DT, 
CR_LAB_TUMORMARKER.CR_LAB_TUMORMARKER,
CR_SURGERY.CR_SURGERY_SPEC
```

Comment: As you are not using any aggregate functions, the `group by` is useless. You can simply remove it and use a `distinct` in the select list

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get an error if I don't use the group by due to the way I have the PTFIRSTNAME and PTLASTNAME to show when the query executes. I'll try DISTINCT and see if it will lessen the way the query generates the results. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

difficult to say without knowing more about your tables and data.

Its probably better (if only for readability) not to mix your join methods, so i'd convert the inner join to

```
inner join cr_workupproc on cr_workupproc.FK_SOCRD_ID=patient.SOCRD_ID
```

and CR_DISEASE_HISTORY.FK_SOCRD_ID

your only filter in the query is

```
and PT_STUDY=3
```

but pt_study seems to be a table or is this also a column on some table? if so its probably better to be explicit as to where it is with a table qualifier.

If this is not a column on cr_imaging table, then you probably need to check your table order, as you are probably doing a number of full table scans.

Also you should get an explain plan for the query to see what it is doing which may help you to optimise the query.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've changed around the joins to see if I could lessen the number of rows that return when the query is executed, but I still get multiple lines of the same information. All of them are tables. Not sure what else I could try. Just really blows when I have to generate a report that's huge with the same information repeated.